# How to reduce/simplify fractions completely (C++)

Tags: c++, class, struct, fractions

I cannot for the life of me fathom **why** I'm getting infinite values returned when I input a normal fraction into the code. Everything but the GCD (Greatest common divisor) seems to be working.

Is there a blatantly obvious logic error somewhere within this?

I've done my research and found various answers to the question, I mean Wikipedia even GIVES YOU code to do it, but I'd like to figure out how to make it work the way I've coded it the way it is now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
private:
   double num;
   double den;
   double fraction;
   double temp;
public:
   void setNum();
   void setDen();
   int getNum();
   int getDen();
   void lcdOutput();
   void decOutput();
   int gcd();
};

void Fraction::setNum(){
   cout << "Enter a value for your numerator: " << endl;
   cin >> num;
}

void Fraction::setDen(){
    cout << "Enter a value for your denominator: " << endl;
    cin >> den;
}

int Fraction::getNum(){
    return num;
 }

 int Fraction::getDen(){
     return den;
  }

int Fraction::gcd(){

    Fraction set;
    if(num > den){
       if(fmod(num, den) == 0){
          den = temp;
          return temp;
       }
       else{
          den = fmod(num, den);
          set.gcd();
       }
    }
    else{
       if(fmod(den, num) == 0){
          num = temp;
          return temp;
       }
       else{
          num = fmod(den, num);
          set.gcd();
       }
    }
 }

void Fraction::lcdOutput(){
    Fraction set;
    set.gcd();
    num = num / temp;
    den = den / temp;
    cout << "Fraction in lowest terms: " << num << "/" << den << endl;
}

void Fraction::decOutput(){
   double decimal = num / den;
   cout.precision(4);
   cout << "The fraction in decimal form is: " << decimal << endl;
}

int main(){

    Fraction set;

    set.setNum();
    set.setDen();
    set.getNum();
    set.getDen();
    set.lcdOutput();
    set.decOutput();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the constructor for Fraction? I don't see how 'temp' is being assigned.

Comment: You use `temp` without ever assigning it a value.

Comment: The gcd() function looks wrong. Why is it creating a new fraction? Also, not all code paths actually return a value.

Comment: You ask 'is there an obvious logic error', the answer is 'several'. The uninitialized temp variable. The incorrect use of the set variable to create a loop. It's hard to understand why you think this code is correct.

Comment: What did you observe when using the debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I can determine just by stepping through your code.

Starting at main, you instantiate an instance of type `Fraction` named `set`. You assign its numerator and denominator via calls to `set.setNum()` and `set.setDen()`. The calls to `getNum()` and `getDen()` do nothing in this case, as they are not being assigned to anything.

Then you call `lcdOutput()`, so let us begin stepping through that.
You begin by instantiating a LOCAL instance of Fraction (not sure why you want to do this, it appears to me that this may be a conceptual mistake), and then call `set.gcd()` for that local instance. Calling `set.gcd()` will call the method for THAT INSTANCE, and it seems to me that what you really want is `this->gcd()` or simply `gcd()`.

You follow up by setting `num = num / temp` and `den = den / temp`, but `temp` is still uninitialized at this point. If the variable is left uninitialized, it can (and usually is) pointing to `garbage`. This probably explains why you are getting nonsensical values returned.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and figured it out on my own. I saw some of the comments and noticed my very large conceptual and logical errors. Here's to anyone that has the same question!

```
int gcd(double num, double den){
    if(den == 0){
       return num;
    }
return gcd(den, fmod(num, den));
}

void Fraction::lcdOutput(){
    double temp = gcd(num, den);
    cout << "Fraction in lowest terms: " << num / temp << "/" << den / temp << endl;
}
```